# updating vim causes usb mouse to freeze

Tags: gnome, mouse, vim

I wanted syntax highlighting in vim. I read in some forum that I should do:

`sudo apt-get install vim`

I guess there were a lot of dependencies, so it took a while. I typed "YES" a few times without really reading the prompts.

My computer restarted and now my mouse & internet don't work.
I suspect something got messed up in gnome.

I should mention that things were working perfectly before I ran the command to update vim (namely, my mouse and internet were working).

How to fix?

I believe I'm using 8.04.

**EDIT: More Info **

`cat /etc/issue` = Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS \n \l

`/var/log/messages` is empty.

`cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE` =

(EE) module ABI major version (7) doesn't match the server's version (2)

(EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module requirement mismatch, 0)

(EE) fglrx(0): atiddxDriScreenInit failed, GPS not initialized.

(EE) No input driver matching 'mouse'

**EDIT: Attempt 1**

I tried the following ([as mentioned here](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/X/Config/Input#Troubleshooting)):

`$ sudo update-rc.d -f gdm remove #get rid of the old boot symlinks`

`$ sudo update-rc.d gdm defaults 25 #add the new ones with a higher priority`

I restarted and got an IRQ 19 Nobody Cared error.

Comment: This question is a little vague on information. in a console, cat /etc/issue to find out what version of ubuntu you are running. Have you looked into your /var/log/messages and /var/log/Xorg.0.log for any panic, error, debug messages that would be of use? It may simply be that your XOrg config was over-written by a package. You can try logging in and running

Comment: This looks interesting. How do I fix an over-written XOrg config? Your comment was cut-off

Comment: reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XORGHardy and https://wiki.edubuntu.org/X/Config/Input

Comment: I restarted and got an IRQ 19 Nobody Cared error. #epic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have gleaned from google, it appears that your update was 'partial' and that some of your XOrg modules did not get upgraded along with your X binaries that were updated. Try re-running a full system update.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade (if sudo apt-get upgrade does not solve the issue)
```

this time, please take your time, examine the prompts that its asking you.

*If this fails to resolve the situation*, I'm not sure that anything short of:

1. ripping apart your install package by package to find the culprit, or
2. doing a full reinstall, would solve your issue.

[offtopic] When it comes to X failing I'm just happy we arent in the 90's when XFree86 ruled the X user sphere. That was a dependency nightmare. [/offtopic]

Comment: I don't have the patience to resolve these issues. I will just use this as an opportunity to upgrade to ubuntu 10.10 and reinstall everything. There are no bugs in that version, correct? ;)

Comment: I wouldn't say *no* bugs, but its running *VERY* stable for me.

Comment: Upgrading is the right answer. The install was ~30 mins and now my vim does syntax highlighting.